# How to set up comma delimiter to export each cell from php to csv

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have a php script that exports a data from mysql into the csv. Everything worked fine, when the script was smaller but now, when it reaches a numerous code lines it doesn't do the job.

**PROBLEM:** it export csv file regularly, but all the tables results are in the first cell of excel. It is supposed to fill each cell - it should recognize in database where there is a comma, then use delimiter and split into cells separately.

So, the delimiter is not working and I don't know why. It should use commas and split it, and it should use | to split again.

This is the code:

```
$link = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die("Can not connect." . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db) or die("Can not connect.");
$result = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM ".$table."");
$columnName = array();
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) 
{
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
    {
        $columnName[] = $row['Field'];
        $i++;
    }
}
$columnName[] .= "\n";
$needle = '|';
$values = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".$table." where id=".$id."");
while ($rowr = mysql_fetch_row($values)) 
{
    for ($j=0;$j<$i;$j++) 
    {
        $colName = $columnName[$j];
        $count = strlen($rowr[$j]) - strlen(str_replace(str_split($needle), '', $rowr[$j]));
        if ($count > 1)
        {
            for($p=0;$p<$count;$p++)
            {
                $colName .= ",";
            }
            $columnName[$j] = $colName;
            $csv_output_column_names .= $columnName[$j].", ";
            $csv_output_column_values .= str_replace('|',',',$rowr[$j]).", ";
        }
        else 
        {
            $csv_output_column_names .= $columnName[$j].", ";
            $csv_output_column_values .= $rowr[$j] .", ";
        }
    }
    $csv_output_column_values .= "\n";
}
$csv_output = $csv_output_column_names."\n".$csv_output_column_values;
$filename = $file."_".date("Y-m-d");
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-disposition: csv" . date("Y-m-d") . ".csv");
header("Content-disposition: filename=".$filename.".csv");
print $csv_output;
exit;
?>
```

Comment: Why are you inventing the wheel? Seems that you just miss quotes around your cells.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend rolling your own CSV solution.  Instead, use [fgetcsv](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) and [fputcsv](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php)

Comment: Where did I missed the quotes?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you're not quoting fields as Excel expects it.

Instead of reinventing the wheel, you should use the already existing [fgetcsv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) and [fputcsv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) functions.

Normally these are used to write to files, but you can create a file handle to standard out so that they're printed to screen.  For example:

```
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-disposition: csv" . date("Y-m-d") . ".csv");
header("Content-disposition: filename=".$filename.".csv");

// $lines is a 2D array with all rows and their column data
// $columns is a 1D array with each row's columns (see examples from fputcsv documentation)
$out = fopen("php://stdout", "w");
foreach ($lines as $columns) { fputcsv($out, $columns); }
fclose($out);
```

Comment: You need quotes around all of the text fields.  For example, `John,Smith,Address,Age` won't work with Excel, but `"John","Smith","Address",Age` will.

Answer (score 0):

You need to care about memory to begin with, including this solves the problem delimited CSV.

Example:

```
$file = new SplFileObject('php://output', 'w');
$file->fputcsv($rowr, ';', '"');
```